# многопоточность, ошибка thread 2: exc_bad_access

Tags: c++

Изучаю многопоточность в С++. Сделал простую программку на создание и вывод двумерного массива. Если массив больше 50х50 элементов то должен работать поток если меньше то работать должно без потоков. Но при работе с потоком программа выдает ошибку которая видна на скрине. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void arrayBig(int rowLength, int columnsLength)
{
    int i, j;
    int arr[1000][1000];

    for (i = 0; i <= rowLength - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= columnsLength - 1; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= rowLength - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= columnsLength - 1; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

int arrayLitle(int rowLength, int columnsLength)
{
    int i, j;
    int arr[1000][1000];

    for (i = 0; i <= rowLength - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= columnsLength - 1; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= rowLength - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= columnsLength - 1; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return arr[i][j];
}

int main()
{
    int columnsLength = 0, rowLength = 0;
    cout << "Укажите длину массива!\n";
    cout << "Введите размер ряда: ";
    cin >> rowLength;
    cout << "Введите размер столбцов: ";
    cin >> columnsLength;

    if ((rowLength >= 50) || (columnsLength >= 50))
    {
        cout << "Работают потоки!"  << endl;
        std::thread aB(arrayBig, rowLength, columnsLength);

        if (aB.joinable())
            aB.join();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Справимся без потоков!!!" << endl;
        arrayLitle(rowLength, columnsLength)
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, я бы не назвал это многопоточностью... Вы просто делаете то же, что в основном потоке, в другом. Ну да ладно...

Но у вас для

```
int arr[1000][1000];
```

требуется, грубо говоря, 4 мегабайта стека. Не многовато ли? попробуйте выделять эту память динамически, или потренируйтесь на массиве, скажем, 100 на 100...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, помогло! Сделал динамическую память. Я еще не особо знаю что да как в многопоточность, первый день только изучаю. Еще раз спасибо.